# Cannot make custom search permalink to work in a fully custom theme. Search string $_GET['s'] is always empty

Tags: permalinks, search

I am learning to build a fully custom WordPress theme. I have a search form

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url() ?>/">
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" id="s" name="s" required />
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

which renders the following HTML:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://local.devsite.com/">
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" id="s" name="s" required />
   <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

In my `search.php` template, I currently have the following code to check whether everything works as desired:

```
if( empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    echo 'No search';
    exit;
}

$s = $_GET['s'];
echo $s;
```

When I run `http://local.devsite.com/?s=sedan`, I get the value of `$_GET['s']` printed on the search page perfectly

However, I want the URL to look like the following:
`http://local.devsite.com/search/sedan`, so I added the following code in my theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function yd_change_search_url() {
    if (  is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yd_change_search_url' );
```

After adding the code, I resaved `Settings > Permalinks`. But when I run `http://local.devsite.com/search/sedan`, I get **No Search** message on the search page.

The phrase **No Search** is printed when an empty `$_GET['s']` is encountered according to the following code that I have added in `search.php` template.

```
if( empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    echo 'No search';
    exit;
}

$s = $_GET['s'];
echo $s;
```

What I am doing wrong? I am following [this tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-search-url-slug-in-wordpress/).

My ultimate goal is to build a URL with multiple query strings, i.e.
`http://local.devsite.com/?s=sedan&mfg=2010&model=Mark%20X&cond=used,`

which would ultimately transform after rewriting to this
`http://local.mydev.com/sedan/2010/mark-x/used`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The error was in my code in `search.php` template file.

My previous code was this:

```
if( empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    echo 'No search';
    exit;
}

$s = $_GET['s'];
echo $s;
```

while it should be this:

```
if( empty( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) {
    echo 'No search';
    exit;
}

$s = get_query_var( 's' );
echo $s;
```

Since there is no literal query string in the URL anymore and it has been redirected to a new URL with a different pattern where I won't be able to grab the value using `$_GET['s']`